# Is Deno as fast as Rust?

Tags: node.js, rust, deno

I heard that Deno is built on top of Rust.
Is Deno as fast as Rust, or is Rust faster?
I cannot find a performance comparison between Deno vs Rust or even Deno vs Golang.

Comment: First, it may be helpful to think how you would compare the speeds.

Comment: @phuzi I see a lot of performance benchmark between golang vs nodejs, rust vsn nodejs, golang vs rust but I cannot see rust vs deno.

Comment: Rust is essentially C++ with improved memory management.  So, Rust would be compared to C++.  Rust is used for the internals of Deno just like C++ is used for the internal of node.js.  Rust and Deno are two completely different things.  This would be like asking for a comparison between C++ and node.js.  In BOTH node.js and Deno, your Javascript is run by V8 (the same Javascript engine).

Comment: Deno is a (Typescript) runtime. Rust is a programming language. How could you possible try to compare their "speed", which is a property of a program exection?

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71979/why-are-some-programming-languages-faster-or-slower-than-others and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40400/what-determines-the-speed-of-a-programming-language

Comment: Deno still has a runtime, which increases overhead. However, 1.6+ compiles to native. Not sure how it handles boxing and unboxing. Would be interesting if it got to the point where it could tree-shake even the runtime.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Deno is slower than Rust. Mainly because Rust is faster than JavaScript. Aside from that all your JavaScript code is run by v8 not Rust.

Runtime methods such as HTTP Requests, file system operations are written in Rust but those calls have the overhead of going from JavaScript to Rust and back again to JavaScript.

In any case, **you should compare it to Node.js** instead which is an equivalent comparison. Since Deno is a Runtime & Rust a programming language.

Comment: thanks, so the performance between nodejs and deno should be likely the same, right?

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon - "Performance" overall  between Deno and node.js is not something I've seen anyone attempt to characterize because that's such a broad thing to do.  I have seen one benchmark about http requests and node.js could do more requests/sec, but Deno had a lesser max latency.

Comment: Aside from that, Deno is still very new, and a lot will change, so I would wait before taking into consideration any performance comparisons.

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon - FYI, pure Javascript performance should be identical or nearly identical between node.js and V8 because they use the same V8 Javascript engine.  Differences would be in the library support because the libraries are completely different implementations written in different languages.  Deno is brand new and a clean design, but node.js is mature and has some backward compatibility baggage to deal with.  Of much bigger difference when solving real world problems is the tens of thousands of available NPM modules for node.js which don't exist for Deno.

Answer (score 7):

Deno is just a runtime like node js. Comparison does not make sense since one is the language and the other is an application.

But if you ask if a server running on Deno can be faster than a server written directly in Rust, that depends on the implementation. However, since it is another layer of abstraction and different jobs delegated to different technologies, like JavaScript engine to V8 (written in c++), event loop to tokio(written in Rust) it is not very likely. You can optimize a server written in Rust to squeeze out the last drop of performance for your use case, but that can not be the case with Deno.

One thing to note here, you choose the right tool for the job. Deno may not provide the level of speed Rust delivers but it maybe good fit for prototyping or writing tools with.

Answer (score 7):

Taking a look at the [architecture](https://deno.land/manual/contributing/architecture) will help you understand why this question is not appropriate from a technical perspective.

Deno and Rust are not equivalent, they are different kinds of technology.

As stated already `Deno` is a runtime (for this context: like an application server) that is built with multiple components written in different languages. Rust is a *language*, not an application server.

Deno uses rust for most of the core inner components.

Hypothetically, if you run Rust code directly then it will perform "better" because it doesn't have to go through a platform lifecycle steps, but that's not the point.

Not only the difference in performance would be irrelevant for 99% of apps, but you won't have a platform to work with where you have libs and integration to develop what matters which is your application code, which happens to be JavaScript or TypeScript.

[image]